# Django multiprocessing multiple APIs in separate Pools

Tags: python, django, multiprocessing

My problem seems a bit complex as compared to all other similar solutions I have searched for here.

I have three different functions developed in my views.py as three different APIs. Suppose I have 16 GB and 8 cores machine available for it. I want to create three separate pools for each API in such a way that Pool-1 (for API-1) is assigned 4 cores (and 8 GB if that is even possible), Pool-2 is assigned 2 cores (and 4 GB) and Pool-3 is assigned remaining 2 cores (and remaining 4 GB).

Now suppose user A makes a request for API-1 (which goes in Pool-1). As soon as the request is made, I dont want to wait for it to finish but only store the process id. Now if user B makes a request say after few hours for API-1 but all 4 cores in Pool-1 are already running, it will wait for any one to finish and basically goes into queue-1 (for Pool-1) even though cores for Pool-2 and Pool-3 are available.

So three separate pools managing three different APIs here in same machine. Below is a rough code of views.py of what I am trying to achieve.

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool


pool1 = Pool(processes=4)       #defining outside so as to keep the same pool for all users for mulitple requests        
pool2 = Pool(processes=2)              
pool3 = Pool(processes=2)              

def function1(params):
     code goes here...

def function2(params):
     code goes here...

def function3(params):
     code goes here...


@api_view(["POST"])
def api_1(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        pool1.map(function1, request.data['params']) 
        #store process id here in a database        
        return HttpResponse("SUCCESS")

@api_view(["POST"])
def api_2(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        pool2.map(function2, request.data['params'])
        return HttpResponse("SUCCESS")


@api_view(["POST"])
def api_3(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        pool3.map(function3, request.data['params'])
        return HttpResponse("SUCCESS")
```

Can this be achieved or even advised? What will be a better way for implementing it if not this.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This can be done through a scheduler like `PBS Torque`, `Oracle Grid Engine` (OGE) or `Slurm`. You can create the queues and submit jobs to these queues and check if the job is done or not or not.

Comment: But is it possible to create multiple `Pool` in python ?

Comment: You won't need that,  The scheduler will manage that for you. and you submit the job and it will where and when will it run.